# What happens when I reference a memory address not allocated by me?

Tags: c, pointers

Suppose I have the following code:
`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char s1[] = "abcd", c;
    scanf("%c", c);
    char* pToC = strchr(s1, c);
    if (pToC)
    {
        if (*(pToC - 1) == a)
        {
            printf("%c", c);
        {
    }
return 0;
}
```

`
What happens in this situation, if I input "a"?
I have a similar situation in my program and am thinking of what happens. In my program I have to check if the word found with strstr() has a space before it, but the result of strstr() could point also to the first char of the string.
Best wishes and thanks in advance!,
K.

I expect it to just work only when I input "b".

Edit:
Since the comment has a max character limit, I will put the exact code here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>

char* WordReplace(char* input, const char* word, const char* replacement)//EXERCISE 13
{
    if (input == 0 || *input == 0 || word == 0 || *word == 0 || replacement == 0 || *replacement == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int inputLength = strlen(input), wordLength = strlen(word), replacementLength = strlen(replacement);
    char* buffer = input;
    while (strstr(buffer, word))
    {
        char* firstChar = strstr(buffer, word), * nextChar = strstr(buffer, word) + wordLength;
        if ((firstChar == input && *nextChar == ' ') ||
            (firstChar == input && *nextChar == 0) ||
            (*(firstChar - 1) == ' ' && *nextChar == ' ') ||
            (*(firstChar - 1) == ' ' && *nextChar == 0))
        {
            buffer = strstr(buffer, word);
            char* output = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (inputLength - wordLength + replacementLength + 1));
            memmove(output, input, sizeof(char) * (buffer - input));
            if (buffer != input)
            {
                output[buffer - input - 1] = ' ';
            }
            output[buffer - input] = 0;
            strcat(output, replacement);
            strcat(output, buffer + wordLength);
            return output;
        }
        buffer = strstr(buffer, word) + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char thirteenInput[] = "My name is Karl", thirteenWord[] = "My", thirteenReplacement[] = "Your";//INPUT
    printf("WordReplace\n%s, %s, %s\n", thirteenInput, thirteenWord, thirteenReplacement);
    char* thirteenOutput = WordReplace(thirteenInput, thirteenWord, thirteenReplacement);
    if (thirteenOutput)
    {
        printf("%s\n\n", thirteenOutput);
        free(thirteenOutput);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Word was not found / input error!\n\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The title makes it sound like you've read about undefined behavior but want details? Correct?

Comment: To begin with, `scanf("%c", c);` will not work as the `scanf` function expects a pointer to the character variable. To continue `a` is a variable not a character. To continue even further, for any pointer `p` and index `i` the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`, which means `*(pToC - 1)` is the same as `pToC[-1]` which will only be valid if `pToC` doesn't point to the first character in `s1`.

Comment: Fix the code to something that compiles so that your question is clear.

Comment: Re “ In my program I have to check if the word found with strstr() has a space before it”: An easy way to handle this is to create some buffer for the string to be scanned, say `char buffer[100]`, but, when putting the string into the buffer, start it at `buffer[1]` instead of `buffer[0]`. In `buffer[0]`, put some character that will give the desired result for the test you want to perform. Then you can easily test `buffer[i-1]` without having to worry about whether `i` is zero (as long as it is not negative).

Comment: I have edited the post to include the code from the exact program. I do not wish to create a buffer, since that requires extra resources. My question, when simplified, is as follows: Can I reference an array at [x-y-1] if x and y could be equal?

Comment: Re “I do not wish to create a buffer, since that requires extra resources”: Using one byte more in an array will use less resources than any other solution that requires even a single extra instruction.

Answer (score 0):

If `array` is defined as an array, and certain special circumstances do not apply, then accessing `array[-1]` is not defined by the C standard. If the program even attempts to calculate the address `array - 1`, the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

When an array is accessed with the subscription notation, as in `array[i]`, C 2018 6.5.2.1 2 defines it to be equivalent to `(*((array) + (i)))`. Then 6.5.6 8 defines the `+` with an array and an integer:

> … If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined…

Since an element indexed with −1 is neither an element of the array nor one past the last element (in the forward direction; one before the first element is not included here), the behavior is undefined.

Even if you know where the array happens to be located in memory and know what data is located before it, that does not mean an array access with index −1 will be safe or will access the data located before the array. Because the behavior is not defined by the C standard, the compiler may, during optimization, transform the program in ways you do not expect, so that the array access produces behavior other than accessing the prior memory.

### Note

As an example of special circumstances, if we have a `char` pointer `p` pointing into a structure that contains an array, we can do address arithmetic with `p` as long as the result remains inside the structure or one past its last byte, even if `p` points into the array but the addition produces a result before the array.